# DisplayCards Func : Getting an error

Tags: c++

So I have this program that asks the user to enter in 5 guesses for a deck of 18 cards.  After guessing them, I have to display both the user guesses, and the seeded generated computers cards. This is my code and I am getting this error

```
309 34  [Error] conversion from 'std::string [19] {aka std::basic_string<char> [19]}' to non-scalar type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' requested
```

```
void DisplayCards(int* user, int* generatedCards)
{
    cout << "Users Guess" << "\t\t\t" << "Generated Cards" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        // Get the names of the choices from the deck
        std::string UserChoice = CARDS;
        std::string GeneratedCard = CARDS;
        // print the names side by side
        cout << UserChoice << "\t\t\t" << GeneratedCard << endl;
    }
```

My `CARDS` are a global as:

```
std::string CARDS[19] = {"nothing","red circle","red square","red triangle","blue circle","blue square",
 "blue triangle","yellow circle","yellow square","yellow triangle","orange circle",
 "orange square" ,"orange triangle","purple circle","purple square",
 "purple triangle","green circle","green square","green triangle"};

std::string  CARDS[19]={"nothing","red circle","red square","red triangle","blue circle","blue square",
 "blue triangle","yellow circle","yellow square","yellow triangle","orange circle",
 "orange square" ,"orange triangle","purple circle","purple square",
 "purple triangle","green circle","green square","green triangle"};
```

Comment: `UserChoice` is a `std::string` and `CARDS` is an array of `std::string`s... your assignment is bogus.

Comment: Any ideas to fix this?  I know its bogus lol  I'm new to c++

Answer (score 0):

Your error will be fixed by addressing these statements:

```
std::string UserChoice = CARDS;
std::string GeneratedCard = CARDS;
```

You need to index the array to obtain the proper value for these variables.

Your function parameters are intended to be the arrays containing the five guesses and generated cards, so your function then becomes:

```
void DisplayCards(int* user, int* generatedCards)
{
    cout << "Users Guess" << "\t\t\t" << "Generated Cards" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        // Get the names of the choices from the deck
        std::string UserChoice = CARDS[user[i]];
        std::string GeneratedCard = CARDS[generatedCards[i]];
        // print the names side by side
        cout << UserChoice << "\t\t\t" << GeneratedCard << endl;
    }
}
```

The function parameters are pointers to the first element of the array that is presumably being passed in via the call to this function I cannot see. You'll likely want to include some more error checking, but the gist of it is you can index your input arguments the same way you would a normal array, using your `i` counter as the index number. You'll get bogus data and perhaps a segmentation fault if your arrays are not the proper size when you run the code, but that's up to you to learn on your own.

Hope this helps.

Comment: void DisplayCards (int *, int *); (15 points)
DisplayCards is passed the computer’s and the player’s card arrays. 
It displays the two sets of cards side by side, by color and shape, not by integer! Has no cin's.         Thats the idea for the func.  I can only address them using pointers, and only pass to pointers to this function, if it will help I can post my entire code.

Hint:  Use the card mapping array to look up the integer and get the string representing the card.